# Dataframe display function in pyspark on databricks platform

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am new to databricks, i was studing topic dataframe in pyspark

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(salesPath)
display(df)
```

Above is my code , i m not getting ,what actually the up arrows do?
and why this beautiful df.display not included in Apache pyspark documentation?

[image: pyspark-display-function-databricks]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Arrows are used to sort the displayed portion of the dataframe.  But please note that the `display` function shows at max 1000 records, and won't load the whole dataset.

The `display` function isn't included into PySpark documentation because it's specific to Databricks.  Similar function also exist in Jupyter that you can use with PySpark, but it's not part of the PySpark.  (you can use `df.show()` function to display as text table - it's a part of the PySpark's DataFrame API)

Comment: Thank you Alex,got doubt cleared,and practiced Handson as well,verified ,thanks.